# I am looking for a specific range of paragraph in the word document by using python, but there is no result come out

Tags: python, for-loop, doc

Trying to extract session 8's paragraph in the word document, which has two paragraph, but cannot be success.

```
from docx.api import Document

doc = Document(r'C:\Users\hello.docx')

word = r"Participating countries"

ind = [i for i, para in enumerate(doc.paragraphs) if word in para.text]

if ind:
    for i, para in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
        if i == ind[0:1]:
            print(para.text)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you link your document? Have you tried to debug your code? Is the `for` loop executes as expected?

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I figure out the problem may be "ind[0:1]" are not correct, it only can be ind[0] or ind[1]